# heroku looking for a staging.log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, heroku

Our heroku staging app is crashing on start up due to not being able to find a staging.log . This seems pretty odd since it should just be outputting everything to development.log, so I am not exactly sure what is going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is the stack trace:

```
2012-04-18T19:20:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-04-18T19:20:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-18T19:20:37+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-04-18T19:20:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 49887`
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.0.3 application starting in staging on http://0.0.0.0:49887
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/staging.log (Errno::ENOENT)
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `initialize'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:247:in `new'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:247:in `block in build_app'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:243:in `reverse_each'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:243:in `build_app'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-04-18T19:20:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-04-18T19:20:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-18T19:20:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app should be outputting its logs to STDOUT, not to a file on the server. See the logging article on the Dev Center for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Heroku automatically injects the [rails_log_stdout](https://github.com/ddollar/rails_log_stdout) to your app on deploy which fixes Rails default logging, so I'm not sure why that isn't happening here. Do you see the following lines output when you deploy to Heroku?

```
-----> Rails plugin injection
   Injecting rails_log_stdout
   Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

Comment: Yeah I know this is pretty odd. Those lines are in the output when I deploy. I even added a staging.log file to the project, just to see if that would fix it by pure luck, and then pushed up and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Rethinking this I might possibly have a RAILS::Logger statement somewhere and that could possibly be my problem. Lemme just grep for that real quick... 
And yeah I had a Logger.new(STDOUT) declared in my environments.rb file. Removing it fixed my problem. Botch job on my part, but thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a config/environments/staging.rb file ensure that you've set both your RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV to 'staging'.

```
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --app myapp-staging
heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=staging --app myapp-staging
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#webserver) that specifies which environement you want to run?  I don't believe this is required by Heroku, but it allows you to specify the enviornment, among other things.